# Find point on a line a certain distance away from another point

Tags: geometry

I have a line defined by two points within the line, $A(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $B(x_2, y_2, z_2)$.

I have a third point $P(x_3, y_3, z_3)$.

How do I find the coordinates of the points on the line $AB$ which are $d$ units away from $P$ ?

Comment: Find the perpendicular distance of $P$ from the line, then slide along it either way, through a distance you get from Pythagoras.

Comment: @J.G. how do I "slide along" it?

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't think that's a dupe. Looks like they asked for finding a point _on the line_. I have 3 points. 2 define a line, one is away from it. If it is a dupe, idk how to re-apply the answer from the other question to this one.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  i have reopened it.  J.G.'s hint is a good one to make it a duplicate.  If the distance from $P$ to the closest point on the line $Q$ is $p$, you want a point on the line that is $\sqrt {d^2-p^2} $ away from $p$.  Now apply [the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678685/finding-a-point-d-distance-away-from-another-point-only-given-a-slope)

Comment: Intersect the line with a sphere centered at $P$.

Comment: @amd idk how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you write out $\|A+\alpha(B-A)-P\|^2=d^2$ you get a quadratic equation in $\alpha$. You can solve for $\alpha$ with standard methods.